# match the n th number in an HTML regex java

Tags: java, regex

Hello i need to find the second occurrence of a match in a string

I have a string like "

```
<span class="test">
  example
</span>
<span class="test">
  example1
</span>
<span class="test">
  example2
</span>
```

i need to extract the example 1 from the content i tried `(?:<span class="test"){2}(.*?)</span>` but its not working.

Please dont say that not to use HTML parser with regex. I am aware of that i have no choice.

Comment: Why no choice? what other limitations are there that we must not hit in suggesting answers?

Comment: Regex is the wrong answer here, if there is some external reason why you think you have no choice please include it. Have you tried just extracting any `example`? (Start with simpler problem.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
(?:<span class="test".*?</span>)\s*<span[^>]*>\s*(.*?)\s*</span>
```

The desired result is the only matched group.  For this to work you need to use the `DOTALL` flag.

Comment: -1 Why is this the accepted answer?  This regex doesn't work.

Comment: @Sepster test it [here](http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html) with DOTALL enabled.

Comment: But until now you made no mention of this regex requiring single-line mode (DOTALL) being enabled.  Update your answer and I'll remove the downvote.  Further, what's the point of the (non-capturing) group around the first half of the regex? And why differing patterns in the first opening `<span...>` tag and the second opening `<span...>` tag, to match the same text?

Answer (score 1):

The following regex:

`<span class="test">\s*(.*?)\s*</span>`

Will produce the following captures:

```
        [0] =>   example
        [1] =>   example1
        [2] =>   example2
```

You can reference whichever one you like.

But if for some reason you can't reference a specific capture (I can't imagine why not, so this is kind of academic), then the following will return the second one:

`<span class="test">(?s).*?</span>\s*<span class="test">\s*(.*?)\s*</span>`

Note the use of "single line mode", specified by `(?s)`.  This means the `.` will also match new-line characters. In Java this can be enabled by using the `DOTALL` option if you're using the `.compile()` approach.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
String text = "<span class=\"test\">  example</span>\n<span class=\"test\">  example1</span>\n<span class=\"test\">  example2</span>";
Matcher m1 = Pattern.compile("<span class=\\\"test\\\">(.*?)<\\/span>").matcher(text);
ArrayList<String> matches = new ArrayList<String>();
while(m1.find()){
   matches.add(m1.group(1).trim());
}
System.out.println(matches.get(1));
```

Comment: Hey brother, this will only work if there's no line breaks in the target text.  Add `(?s)` to allow your captured `.` to match line-breaks (although then you'd need to somehow "trim" these out of your capture group too).  Rather than calling `.trim()` this can be handled in the regex too, by adding optional (non-greedy) whitespace either side of your capture group, eg `\s*?(.*?)\s*?` (in which case, the `(?s)` is no longer required as `\s` will capture line breaks). ;-)

Comment: @Sepster Hi, it matches even if there are new lines (see updated string) you can test it yourself , regarding trim you are right but i was too lazy to do it from regex :)

Comment: I tested the regex itself in several Java regex testers, and it only works if DOTALL option is turned on (Java equivalent of ?s option). Perhaps this is on by default, when executing from Java code? but I didn't think so? "_The regular expression . matches any character except a line terminator unless the DOTALL flag is specified._" http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

Comment: First of all pls test it for real not just using Java regex testers , second the default flag is 0 that means no mode is selected but since i do not specify the begin ^ and end $ i think by default is matching new lines : "By default, the regular expressions ^ and $ ignore line terminators and only match at the beginning and the end, respectively, of the entire input sequence"

Comment: The behaviour of those anchors does change in multiline mode vs no mode, yes. But that has no relationship to a dot's ability to match new line characters. If your Java implementation is matching new lines with a dot, when not using single line mode (or DOTALL) then IMHO it's contrary to typical regex behaviour.